# Change timestamps in a cycle

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel file with different cycles and each cycle has several actions and there is a timestamp connected to the start of each action. I would like to shorten the cycles, so that they won't be longer than 40-45 minutes. There are thousands of cycles. The problem is, if I change one timestamp I have to change all of them. Any idea for a formula that could do this for me (see the timestamps that are in that cycle - cycles have unique ID's, but there is different number of actions in each cycle; change the beginning of an action to shorten cycle; change all the timestamps). Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share some sample data with us,,, along with time intervals you want according to the task!